I got a call trace error from iwlwifi and idk how to fix it
Today I tried suspending my laptop and resuming it on NixOS after fixing something about Nvidia's powerManagment and black screens on GNOME when I noticed the internet was not connecting back, but the NetworkManager service was running it just had to restart.
I tried searching about it after running dmesg and I did not find any answers to the occuring problem so then I scrolled up the dmesg log and found a call trace left by the iwlwifi module.
Any ideas on what to do?
I just know before updating to Nix I ran Arch Linux on Kernel 6.10.9 and now that I updated to NixOS Kernel 6.11 I'm having this issue. I still have the call trace saved on my device in the form of a txt file and I'm too scared to send an e-mail to kernel.org's regressions list because it might have been caused by my own faulty actions.
Bonus information: I am not using every unstable package from NixOS's nixpkgs I'm only using the one for Kernel 6.11 and Nvidia Driver 560
Calltrace: https://pastebin.com/raw/YCZAjAXM

Since iwlwifi failed in __iwl_trans_pcie_grab_nic_access, I would suspect that some  other driver has allocated the NIC. Either sudo journalctl  -b 0, or sudo less /var/log/messages will let you watch your system start up and discover its hardware.

Scrool down to Comment 104 iwlwifi: Timeout waiting for hardware access (CSR_GP_CNTRL 0xffffffff) - MWG100226667

Doing what eyoung100 suggested worked.
I'll just make a service that runs that everytime my system recovers from sleep

Maybe write up the solution and post it as an answer which you can self-accept (after 48 hrs?) to gain valuable reputation points? I will upvote too.

You can remove the affected PCI-E device and then run a rescan to fix this issue
echo 1 > /sys/bus/pci/devices/<mydevice>/remove 
echo 1 > /sys/bus/pci/rescan

And you can create a Systemd service in nix's configuration in order to run it everytime your computer is resumed after a sleep by giving it the value of WantedBy=sleep.target.
systemd.services.reset_wireless_pci_device = {
  script = ''
    echo 1 > /sys/bus/pci/devices/<mydevice>/remove
    echo 1 > /sys/bus/pci/rescan
  '';
  wantedBy = ["sleep.target"];
  serviceConfig = {
    Type = "oneshot";
  };
};

